# How to make '#' be written and taking as value in android

Tags: android

I want to add `#` as value in my program, such as :

```
val square = "#"
```

But it doesn't work ...
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer, it is solved by adding:

```
Uri.encode("#")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

u can add it by addin \ before it like
\#

Comment: it didn't work when i add it , but thank you for contributing